# Parse Json string to find all values of same element

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, object

I have a json as below.

```
{
    "name": "",
    "id": "test1",
    "properties": {
        "name1": [
            {
                "id": "test2",
            },
            {
                "id": "test3"
                }
            }
        ],
        "name3": [
            {
                "id": "test4"


            }
        ],
        "name5": [
            {
                "id": "test7"
            }
        ],
        "name7": [
            {
                "id": "test8"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the above JSON. I am looking to extract values of all properties which has "id". so finally I need a list that has id values as below.

```
{"test2", "test3","test4","test7","test8"}
```

How I can implement this in C#.
Thanks for any suggestions?

Comment: What json library are you using?

Comment: I tried by JsonConvert to convert it into a dynamic type. but I couldn't find how to approach a situation like this?

Comment: I would also want "test1" in the response that I get. as below. 
{"test1","test2", "test3","test4","test7","test8"}

Comment: Please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your mention of `JsonConvert` it seems you are using `Json.NET`. So one of the options is to use json path to extract needed values:

```cs
var js_str= ....;
var jToken = JToken.Parse(js_str);  
var result = jToken.SelectTokens("$.properties.*.[*].id")
    .Values()
    .Select(value => value.Value<string>())
    .ToList();
```

Or you can query you json with [LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm#ID2RBSection).

Or create model that represents your data. There is quite common convention for dictionaries to represent object so something like this will work:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Obj>> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Obj
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(js_str);
var result = deserialized.Properties
    .Values
    .SelectMany(v => v)
    .Select(obj => obj.Id)
    .ToList();
```

**UPD**

To get values of all properties with name == `id` you can do this:

```cs
var res = JObject.Parse(js_str)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "id")
    .Select(p => p.Value.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Or update `Root` model to have `Id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Using JToken.Parse does not need to create the classes, but as I guess you may need not only Ids but some another data too. In this case try this code that is using JsonConvert

```
var json="{\"name\":\"\",\"id\":\"test1\",\"properties\":{\"name1\":[{\"id\":\"test2\"},{\"id\":\"test3\"}],\"name3\":[{\"id\":\"test4\"}],\"name5\":[{\"id\":\"test7\"}],\"name7\":[{\"id\":\"test8\"}]}}";

var jD=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    
var ids=jD.properties.Select(p =>p.Value.Select(v =>v.id ) ).SelectMany(i=> i).ToList();
```

output

```
["test2", "test3","test4","test7","test8"]
```

classes

```
public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Name[]> properties { get; set; }
}
public class Name
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```